# Fortran runtime error ... No such file or directory

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I am new to fortran programming. Please, I need to resolve the following problem.

I am working on an open source code
https://github.com/valeriabarra/ThinViscoelasticFilms
and it has the line below in one of the .f90 files.

!!$ output folder

```
CHARACTER(len=*), PARAMETER :: folder='/home/user/Output/000/' ! needs to be changed with your global path
```

I am running gfortran on Ubuntu. So, I changed the directory to:

```
‘/home/viscoexpert/Desktop/ThinViscoelasticFilms-master/output/000/’
```

but it returns the following error mesage:

```
At line 40 of file ../par.f90 (unit = 3)
Fortran runtime error: Cannot open file ‘/home/viscoexpert/Desktop/ThinViscoelasticFilms-master/output/000/range.dat’: No such file or directory


Error termination. Backtrace:
#0 0x7f8d8d0a62ed in ???
#1 0x7f8d8d0a6ed5 in ???
#2 0x7f8d8d0a769d in ???
#3 0x7f8d8d219ecd in ???
#4 0x7f8d8d21a214 in ???
#5 0x55a32fec4a0a in par_
                              at ../par.f90:40
#6 0x55a32fec14b8 in MAIN__
                              at ../main.f90:90
#7 0x55a32fec1bd4 in main
                              at ../main.f90:29
```

Please, how do I specify the correct directory for the output folder?

Comment: Does that directory or file exist?

Comment: Adding to @francescalus comment, do you have permission to read and/or write to that directory or file?

Comment: @francescalus: Yes, it does. I did create .dat files in the directory.  I'm not sure if that's the way to go about it. An example of how to create a similar path/directory would be helpful

Comment: @evets: I'm not sure

Comment: You're working on a Unix-like system.  The command 'ls -l' will tell you if you own the directory hierarchy and whether you have read/write permission.

Comment: Thank you all. The problem has been resolved. I used '/home/viscoexpert/Documents/Output' . I made sure that the cases are correct.